# Multiprocessing on image in python 3 does not give enough performance

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, image-processing, multiprocessing

I'm reading video File from opencv and store their frames in a list, Then I provide this list to face detection function which in turn store the face location in another list, the problem is that when I give an equal number of frame to multiprocessing code and single processing code, the performance is not very different. please check my code, suggest the possible solution. I am using python 3.5, the number of CPU core is 4. Multiprocessing code is supposed to give almost 4 times performance but it only gives few second gains.

**My code:**

```
import cv2,time,dlib,imutils
from multiprocessing import Pool

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
vidcap=cv2.VideoCapture(r'/home/deeplearning/PycharmProjects
     /sjtech/jurassic_park_intro.mp4')


count = 0
frame_list = []

def parallel_detection(f):
      return detector(f,1)

success,image = vidcap.read()
while success:
     print('Read a new frame: ', success)
     frame_list.append(image)
     count += 1
     success,image = vidcap.read()




del frame_list[-1]
print("out of while")

p = Pool()
t1 = time.time()
#below is my multiprocessing code, on 40 frames it takes 42 seconds
face_location=p.map(parallel_detection,frame_list[900:940])
#below is single processing code, it takes 50 seconds
face_location=[detector(frame_list[x],1) for x in range(900,940)]
print(time.time()-t1)
```

Comment: A shot in the dark here-  try `import os; print(os.cpu_count())` and make sure python agrees that there's 4 cores.

Comment: i checked , it have 4 cores

Comment: Try constructing the code in the same manner for the second example: `map(parallel_detection, frame_list[900:940])`, and see how long it takes then. That way we can rule out any factors related to how you're calling detector.

Comment: Can you try just discarding the first 900 frames as you read them - I mean to only save frames 900-940 in your list to see if it is related to memory pressure? Also try adding a line printing out the time at start of `parallel_detection()` to see how many instances are spawned and when.